# Android: static reference / non-static method when using onClickListener();

Tags: android

I want to call the `onClickListener()` but there is a problem

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) from the type View
```

**My relevant code:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
         final String editTextStr = intent.getExtras().getString("url");
        ImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  Uri uri = Uri.parse(putExtra(editTextStr));

              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
              }

            });
```

please help me please

Comment: what is the use if you call setOnClickListener on ImageView?

Comment: It would help to see the relevant `import` statements, to see which classes you are referring to, or use complete class names. Even better, links to the Android API documentation of the relevant classes and quoting the relevant definitions would help people fluent with Java to find quickly and explain why you get this compilation error instead of being annoyed by the expectation that they would need to invest their precious time to search for the references for you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) is a class. By calling the setOnClickListener method on the className you are tring to call Static Method but actually its not a static method.

`final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.<ID in you Layout XML file>);
imageView.setOnClickListener(....);`

Answer (score 0):

ImageView is a class. By calling the setOnClickListener method on the class, you're making a static reference to that method of the class. But the setOnClickListener method is not defined as static.

You need to set the click listener on an object of that class. For instance,

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
myImageView.setOnClickListener(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call onClickListener on a particular instance of your activity.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourref);
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              Uri uri = Uri.parse(putExtra(editTextStr));

              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
              startActivity(intent);
          }

        });
```